# 2003 Alero /highway /rpms

Tags: transmission

I have 2003 Oldsmobile Alero, it runs at around 4000 rpm doing 55 and at 70 its close to 5000, i know this isn't normal.Is it not shifting correctly? I haven't noticed any issues with the transmission.Is it something simple im able to correct myself or more serious problem

Comment: What would normal RPM be for 70mph?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on engine size /power ,but that is too much RPM . Any car I have had will be less than 2000 at 55 mph. Apparently your transmission is not up-shifting or the torque converter is stuck in " maximum ". I had an Olds with a defective torque converter stuck in "minimum" : the RPM could not reach 2000. You need transmission work which may be expensive but otherwise the engine will not last long at those RPM .( Yes , I know motorcycles normally turn at high RPM with no problem). My 3.5 L Nissan is 1600 RPM at 60 MPH.